# How do I filter for the concentrate of all set filters in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have data in this form:

[image]

In PowerBI, I added another column where I keep only code combinations that consist of one single code. I did this with something like IF(LEN(Code > 1), "", Code). Result:

[image]

This enables me to create a slicer that contains only single codes. I also added a table that shows Codes.

Now, when I select codes in the slicer, I want the table to show these codes, plus the exact combination of it.
For example, when I select A and B, the table should show me A and B and A, B. I don't want it to show A, B, C although it contains A and B.
If I filter for A and B and C, however, I want it to show A and B and C and A, B, C - but not A, B.

How can I achieve that?

All entries in Codes are saved as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a disconnected (not connected to the base table) table for your slicer. Now, if I consider your base table name is - **your_table_name**, you can create the new slicer table with this below code-

```
slicer = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
        your_table_name_8,
        LEN(your_table_name_8[codes]) = 1
    ),
    "code",your_table_name_8[codes]
)
```

After creating the new **slicer** table, check in the model is there any auto relation detected between 2 tables or not. If you find any relation, just **Remove** the relation.

**Now**, create your slicer from the newly created table and create this below measure in your base table **your_table_name**-

```
show_or_hide = 

VAR current_code = MIN(your_table_name_8[codes])

VAR comma_separated_list = 
CALCULATE (
    CONCATENATEX (
        VALUES(slicer[code]),
        slicer[code],
        ","
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    current_code = comma_separated_list || (LEN(current_code) = 1 && CONTAINSSTRING(comma_separated_list,current_code)),
    1,
    0
)
```

lets see the outcome-

[image]

**Finally**, you can apply a visual level filter using the new measure **show_or_hide** and apply a filter so that value with **True** only shown in the visual.

## Reorder Combination

Let we have this following table-

[image]

Now this following code from **Advanced Query Editor** will give the the expected output-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WctRx0nFWitUBsZx1nJRiYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Column1"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "column_name", each "Column-" & [Value]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"column_name", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Index", "column_name", "Value"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns1",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}, {"column_name", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[column_name]), "column_name", "Value", List.Min),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Column-A", "Column-B", "Column-C"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

**Please check what applied in steps one by one for better understanding.** Here is the output with ascending order in the combination-

[image]

Index column added for keep tracking the row from start to end. If you have already a similar column, you can use that column as well.

Comment: Thanks, this looks really nice already! Two things: It might happen that code combinations come in different orders (like A,C,B instead of A,B,C). If you have an idea for that, please share (otherwise I think I can come up with one as well as I have the general setup now). What is more: As show_or_hide is a measure it cannot be used for a filter (as far is I know). How did you think to solve this?

Comment: Hi @Julian, my apology as I forgot that issue for using measure as FILTER. But I have used Measure as filter in my reports several times. Just need to return 0 or 1 in place of TRUE/FALSE. With this change, you can apply filter like "show_hide=1". I tested this again now. I have already changed the Measure code, please check.

Comment: For combination in random order, this is not possible to handle this way :(

Comment: Filtering works!
Are you sure there is no way for the combinations? Like somehow checking if each of the individual codes is contained in comma_separated_list? Or creating multiple comma separated lists (one for each possible combination) and then loop through these while checking if one fo them matches current_code?

Comment: You can do some Transformation in Power Query to create the combination with proper order (ascending) from a randomly generated combination. Then check with this new column.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on how exactly this could be done?

Comment: I will explain shortly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223450/discussion-between-r-r-and-julian).

Comment: I found a solution (at least for my case) that doesn't involve the advanced query editor. As it turned out, my problem was not that the codes in the original table were unordered, but the codes in the slicer (calculated) table. I found (by accident, tbh) that the column gets ordered by wraping the calculation statement in `DISTINCT()`: `slicer = DISTINCT(<the code from above>)`.

Comment: Nice to hear you got the solution :)

Comment: Hello again! Just a little follow-up question: Why does `VAR current_code = MIN(your_table_name_8[codes])` actually give me the current code? I don't really understand some underlying principles, I think..